# Steps to develop Angular2 frent-end application for an existing (Spring security + Spring MVC + Restfull) application?

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

Context : In a Spring back-end, restfull and gwtp frent-end app, I'm trying to migrate the front-end to angular2.

Anyone can help me which steps I should follow?

Is it possible to implement angular side separately and make it together with the rest? but how application parts communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate angular application and you can talk with spring backend by using restful web api. For that you have to convert your backend in rest endpoints.

Comment: Thanks @Prathmesh I'll then focus on angular right now.

Comment: One last thing! Is there anything I should take on consideration while developping the angular side for that propuse?

Comment: The object structure in java and your ts file should be same that is even names of properties should be same. Datatypes it will internally converts. If your names will mismatch then you will not be able to receive that particular value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what we've done: **Spring backend** with Spring Data, Spring Security, Spring SAML2 extension, Spring MVC.

The **Frontend** is a separate codebase, built with `ng-cli`  I would not suggest doing anything silly like putting the Angular2 app into the `WEB-INF` directory of the Java project.

Comment: I already saw before this suggestion to make angular front with Spring back in same server. Thank you for your advice, and I would just ask if there is anything I should take on consideration while developping the angular side?

Comment: Yes, if you use Spring data, avoid hard-coding the rest api urls, make use of the Entities links as much as possible. Also set up Spring Security to set a XCSRF token on the requests, and you might also want to set up a socket communication between backend and frontend to notify the frontend of changes (like backend errors or whatever). Finally make your components as independent as possible, don't put everything into the main App.module, but split it into smaller modules and work out how dependency works in Angular2.

Comment: Yes I did use Spring Data, Spring security and Spring MVC. I'll follow everything you mentioned and make it step by step! I'm grateful for your help.